# decompose "with" statements to various functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I wrote a generic framework that help me to bench-mark code critical sections.

Here is an explanation of the framework and in the end is the problem I am facing and few ideas I have for solutions.

**Basically, I am looking for more elegant solutions**

Suppose I have a function that does this (in pseudo code):

```
#Pseudo Code - Don't expect it to run

def foo():
   do_begin()
   do_critical()
   some_value = do_end()
   return some_value
```

I want to run "do_critical" section many times in loop and measure the time but still get the return value.

so, I wrote BenchMarker class that its api is something like that:

```
#Pseudo Code - Don't expect it to run

bm = BenchMarker(first=do_begin, critical=do_critical, end=do_end)
bm.start_benchmarking()
returned_value = bm.returned_value
benchmark_result = bm.time
```

This Benckmarker internally performing the following:

```
#Pseudo Code - Don't expect it to run

class BenchMarker:    
  def __init__(self):
     .....

  def start_benchmarking(self):
    first()
    t0 = take_time
    for i in range(n_loops):
      critical()
    t1 = take_time
    self.time = (t1-t0)/n_loops

    value = end()
    self.returned_value = value
```

Important to mention that **I also able to pass context between first, critical and end functions**, but I omitted it for simplicity as this is not the gist of my question.

**This framework is working like a charm until the following use case:**

I have the following code

```
#Pseudo Code - Don't expect it to run    

def bar():
  do_begin()

  with some_context_manager() as ctx:
    do_critical()

  some_value = do_end()
  return some_value
```

**Now, after this long introduction (sorry ...), I am getting to the real question.**

I don't want to run the "with statement" in the time measuring loop, but the critical code needs the context manger.

so what I basically want is equivalent to the following decomposing of bar:

```
first ->  do_begin() + "what happens in the with before the with body"
critical -> do_critical()
end -> "what happens after the with body" + do_end()
```

Two Solutions I thought of (but I don't like):

**Solution 1**
Mimic what with does under the hood

- In end of first()m create the context manager object + run it's **enter**() function
- In the start of end(), call the context manager **exit**() function

**Solution 2**
Framework Enhancement to handle CM

Add to the framework a "context work mode" (flag, whatever ...) on which the "start_benchmarking" flow will look like this:

```
#Pseudo Code - Don't expect it to run 

def start_benchmarking(self):
  first() #including instantiating the context manager
  ctx = get_the_context_manager_created_in_first()      

  with ctx ...:

    t0 = take_time
    for i in range(n_loops):
      critical()
    t1 = take_time

  self.time = (t1-t0)/n_loops      
  value = end()
  self.returned_value = value
```

**Any other, more elegant, solutions?**

Answer (score 0):

this is way over-complicated. and i cannot quite figure out why you'd actually want to do this, but assuming that you have reasons, just create a function that does your timing for you:

```
def run_func_n_times(n_times, func, *args, **kwargs):
    start = time.time()
    for _ in range(n_times):
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
    return res, (time.time() - start) / n_times
```

no need for a class, just a simple func:

```
def example():
    do_begin()
    print('look, i am here')
    with ctx() as blah:
        res, timed = run_func_n_times(27, f, foo, bar)
    do_end()
```

Comment: 1. regarding the class vs function - the class does more things that I left out for simplicity.

Comment: Tx @acushner
1. Regarding the class vs function - the class does more things that I left out for simplicity. for example it help to pass parameters between the begin, critical and end.
2. Your solution resembles my solution #2, but what will I do when there is a flow with no context manager involved? I don't want to write an example every time. I want a generic framework that can deal with every flow.